# Array location is becoming 1 automatically

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, c99

As a I have posted the possible solution to a CodeForce Problem which was causing Time Limit Exceed error posted [enter link description here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116756/wet-boxes-problem-counting-points-on-a-triangular-grid), some solutions came. Nevertheless I worked out with another solution..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int greatestX = 0, greatestY = 0;
int counter = 0;

void prune_boxes(int boxes[][greatestY], int x, int y){
  printf("boxes[2][0] = %d\n", boxes[2][0]);
  if (y < 0)
    return;
  else{
    //printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
    if (boxes[x][y] == 0){
      printf("x = %d y = %d\n", x, y);
      counter++;
      boxes[x][y] = 1;
    }
    prune_boxes(boxes, x, y - 1);
    prune_boxes(boxes, x + 1, y - 1);
  }
}


int main() {
  int wetBoxes, i, j;
  scanf("%d", &wetBoxes);
  int coordinates[wetBoxes][2];
  for(i = 0; i < wetBoxes; i++){
    scanf("%d%d", &coordinates[i][0], &coordinates[i][1]);
    if (coordinates[i][0] > greatestX)
      greatestX = coordinates[i][0];
    if (coordinates[i][1] > greatestY)
      greatestY = coordinates[i][1];
  }
  int boxes[greatestY + 1][greatestY + greatestX + 1];
  memset(boxes, 0, sizeof(boxes));
  /*
   for(i = 0; i < greatestY + 1; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < greatestY + greatestX + 1; j++){
      printf("%d ", boxes[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  */

  for(i = 0; i < wetBoxes; i++){
    //printf("value = %d\n", boxes[coordinates[i][0]][coordinates[i][1]]);
    prune_boxes(boxes, coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]);
  }
  printf("counter = %d\n", counter);

return 0;
}
```

Is not causing the the Time Limit Exceed now but it is giving me one less count of any particular value.

Debugging it further I found that for the input of `(1, 3)` the code is not counting the coordinate `(2, 0)`.

Even with further debugging I found that `boxes[2][0]` is becoming 1 before I would actually make that coordinate 1 manually.

The sample output looks like this

```
1
1 3
boxes[2][0] = 0
x = 1 y = 3
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 1 y = 2
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 1 y = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 1 y = 0
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 2 y = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 3 y = 0
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 2 y = 2
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 3 y = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
x = 4 y = 0
boxes[2][0] = 1
boxes[2][0] = 1
counter = 9
```

As you can see that the `boxes[2][0]` from the second recursion level is becoming 1 but **why ?** 
**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't the compiler yell a warning at you passing to `prune_boxes() as 1st parameter something different as expected?

Comment: Yes it does...I find this is the most easiest way to pass a variable length array to a function in c99..can this be the cause of it?..moreover how you would pass vla to a function?

Comment: Use something like `void foo(size_t x, size_t y, int p[x][y]);`. Order matters.

Comment: Also take warnings serious and fix the code until they are gone.

Comment: gcc in c99 mode doesn't give any warning except the unused variable `j`...Moreover how passing `x`, `y` before `p` would make any difference ??

Comment: Tried https://www.codechef.com/ide too in c99 strict mode..No warning too

Comment: "*Moreover how passing x, y before p would make any difference ??*" try it and get enlightened.

Comment: Also you want to enable more warnings be specifying `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion`.

Comment: Please check the edited part of the question

Comment: you don't need `else` after a `return` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get lots of compiler warnings for this part

```
int greatestX = 0, greatestY = 0;
int counter = 0;

void prune_boxes(int boxes[][greatestY], int x, int y){
```

saying that `greatestY` isn't a constant. So how is the function to know the size of the array?

If it accepts `greatestY`as the size at this point, the array would be `int boxes[][0]`, and all accesses would be out-of-range. That surely can create unexpected results.

And the array you pass isn't of those dimensions anyway, but

```
int boxes[greatestY + 1][greatestY + greatestX + 1];
```

Comment: How are you compiling..? are you using `gcc -std=c99`

Comment: gcc accepts variable array sizes (VLA). I used MSVC, which does not. But anyway, you pass an array of a different size from what the function expects.

Comment: Oh..but yes you are right..I passed the array of right size ( `greatestY + greatestX + 1` ) and now it is counting `2, 0` but some other values are taken away..Is it because I passed the array wrongly in the function??

Comment: @MayukhSarkar you have to make sure the declared size of the array matches the array seen in the function signature...  perhaps changing the function signature to `int boxes[][greatestX + greatestY + 1]` would fix

Answer (score 0):

Thanks folks for answering the question looks like the problem was passing the 2D array to the function. `gcc` was not throwing any error or warnings but `clang` was giving some error. Hence I decided to solve it in C++. Here is the solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static int counter;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> boxes;
void prune_boxes(int x, int y){
 if (y < 0)
   return;
 else{
   if (boxes[x][y] == 0){
     boxes[x][y] = 1;
     counter++;
   }
   prune_boxes(x, y - 1);
   prune_boxes(x + 1, y - 1);
 }
}



int main(){
  int wetBoxes;
  std::cin >> wetBoxes;
  std::vector<int> coordinatesX;
  std::vector<int> coordinatesY;
  int input;
  for (int i = 0; i < wetBoxes; i++){
    std::cin >> input;
    coordinatesX.push_back(input);
    std::cin >> input;
    coordinatesY.push_back(input);
  }

  int greatestX = *max_element(coordinatesX.begin(), coordinatesX.end());
  int greatestY = *max_element(coordinatesY.begin(), coordinatesY.end());

  int Y =  greatestY + 1;
  int X =  greatestX + greatestY + 1;
  boxes.resize(X);
  for (int i = 0; i < X; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++){
      boxes[i].push_back(0);
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < wetBoxes; i++){
    prune_boxes(coordinatesX[i], coordinatesY[i]);
    std::cout << counter << std::endl;
    counter = 0;
  }
  return 0;
}
```